# Class constructor throwing attribute error Python

Tags: python

Here is my program structure:

```
class parent(object):
    def __init__(self): pass

    def __post_init_stuff(self):
       #post initialization stuff

class child(parent):
    def __init__(self):
       #dostuff
       self.__post_init_stuff()

def otherfunc(classname, args):
    classname(args)

otherfunc(child)
```

The problem that I'm having is that when `otherstuff(child)` executes, I get this error:

`AttributeError: 'child' object has no attribute '_child__post_init_stuff'`

Any advice?

Comment: You haven't posted any code for `otherstuff`

Comment: That is happening due to [Name mangling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references).

Comment: Also I will add that having __post_init_stuff is a very bad idea. __init__ is already the generic function for stuff that happens, well, at init. If you need to expand that in child then you should call the partens __init__ and then continue with child specific instructions.

Comment: Why are you using double underscores in the first place if you don't want mangled, private-even-from-subclasses names? Literally the only reason to ever use them is to cause exactly this scenario.

Comment: @kindall It was a typo. I edited the question to reflect this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Names that start with `__` in Python are like `protected` in C++. You could name with only one underscore instead or access it as `self._parent__post_init_func`, since this is its mangled name within the scope. I recommend the first thing, since this is ugly and hacky.